# What is wrong with following installation steps of latest nodejs on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Why can't I simply install latest nodejs.
I have executed curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
after which i executed the following

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-33:/$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 188 not upgraded.

ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-33:~$ which node
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-33:~$ which nodejs
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-33:~$ whereis node
node:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-33:~$ whereis nodejs
nodejs:

ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-33:/$ node -v
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
```

OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you tried to run `which nodejs`. I've encountered similar issues with Vagrant provisioning and the solution was to soft link `nodejs` package which is present in `/usr/bin/` to `node` in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try run:

```
which nodejs
```

if this command has a result take that directory location and create a symlink for it with the 'node' name.

The command should look something like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: If you just navigate to /usr/bin/ is there a node file ? Do not trust which and whereis for a second.

Answer (score 0):

purge and installing worked:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs*
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
which nodejs
```

> /usr/bin/nodejs

```
which node
```

> /usr/bin/node

```
node -v
```

> v7.7.3